# Remove a city from being able to purchase product

Tags: magento-1.9, array, remove

So in my explorations I've found that Magento only has the States stored in the back end, but I don't want to remove the entire state, just one city in that state. I've seen options to include a city option, or remove city drop down, but I can't seem to find a way to just remove one city.

Am I just over looking something really basic, or am I going to need to dive into the code and log all the cities in every state and then exclude the one city I don't want to allow to order?

Thanks in advance for reading this, and I'm sorry if I'm asking a dumb question but I just can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do client-side validation as specified by @MageCoder. Another approach is to have server side validation. In onepage checkout when someone fillups the addess and proceed, it send request to `saveShippingAction()` in `Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`. Here you could perform validation.

```
if($data['city'] == 'New York')   
{
    $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method';
    $result['update_section'] = array(
                            'name' => 'shipping-method',
                            'html' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Shipping not allowed'));
    $this->_prepareDataJSON($result);
 }
```

Make sure you override the controller else your customisation will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

- You can create custom validation on that city field
- If user enter that city then it resticct to proceed

https://claireparker.github.io/magento-1-frontend-bits/validation-rule/